# Set 'session' as cookie expiry instead of number [ng2-cookies]

Tags: javascript, html, angular, cookies, angular-cookies

I am using [ng2-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-cookies), and it is clear from [here](https://github.com/BCJTI/ng2-cookies/blob/master/src/cookie.ts#L66) that expiry is expected to be a number.

I want to set expiry as *browser-session* `session` like it appears in dev-tools.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried sending undefined as value to optional param `expiry` and it worked.

```
Cookie.set('token', user.token, undefined, '/');
```

Comment: Sorry no Jaroslaw. I could not find solution, but it striked few mins after i posted the question. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want the expire to set as *session*, you could just send as follow:

```
Cookie.set('token', user.token);
```

And then the expiry will be set to *session* as default. At least, this has definitely worked with me.